# Using image in a template django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to view images, in a template, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Image not displayed (correctly)]

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Название", max_length = 100)
    TYPE_ITEMS = (
        ("shirt", "Футболка"),
        ("shoes", "Обувь"),
        ("bags", "Рюкзаки и сумки"),
        ("heads", "Головные уборы"),
        ("others", "Другое"),
        )
    type_item = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Тип продукта",
                                 choices = TYPE_ITEMS, max_length = 6,
                                 default = "shirt")
    other = models.CharField("другая информация", max_length = 200)
    color = models.CharField("Цвет(а)", max_length = 100)
    cost = models.IntegerField("Стоимость за штуку", default = 0)
    is_available_now = models.BooleanField("Есть ли в наличии?",
                                           default = False)
    available_count = models.IntegerField("Количество в наличии", default = 0)
    photo = models.ImageField("Фото", upload_to = "photos/to_trade")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.color + " (" + str(self.cost) + " грн)"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader ####
from myapp.models import Item

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def goods(request):
    shirts_list = Item.objects.filter(type_item = "shirt")

    template = loader.get_template("goods.html")
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        "shirts_list": shirts_list,})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def contacts(request):
    return render(request, "contacts.html")

def delivery(request):
    return render(request, "delivery.html")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'paporotnik.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = "index"),
    url(r'^goods', views.goods, name = "goods"),
    url(r'^contacts', views.contacts, name = "contacts"),
    url(r'^delivery', views.delivery, name = "delivery"),
    url(r'^photos/to_trade/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve'),
)
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = '(=bk@zukikdq==0dtokjbg-sbgge5zi(^te01+9=w%is-76sxv'
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'paporotnik.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'paporotnik.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "C:\\Python33\\Scripts\\paporotnik\\static"
```

This is my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Товары - Paporotnik.ua</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "{% static 'myapp/style_index.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- Верхняя панель (заголовок) -->
            <div id="header">
                <div style = "float: left; width:100%">
                    <div style = "margin: 0 10%;">
                        <br><h1 id = "heed">Paporotnik.ua</h1><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id = "divLogo">
                    <img id = "logo", width = "125", height = "125">
                </div>
                <div id = "trash" align = "center">
                    <h3>Корзина</h3>
                    <img align = "center", width = "70", height = "50">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Центр, основное содержимое -->
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                    <p align = "center">
                    <h2 align = "center">Футболки</h2>
                    <div align = "center">
                        {% for item in shirts_list %}
                            <img src = "{{item.photo}}", width = "150", height = "250">
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I view the code in a browser, the path is correct:

[image: Path in Browser]

But when I click on the URL, I see this:

[image: Error message]

It tells me that my picture doesn't exist, but it is there!

[image: Local path]

Comment: Try with `{{ item.photo.url }}`

Comment: It doesn't helps (((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that I would like to bring to your notice. `static` stores your css,js and images that are needed for the website frontend. `media` stores all the images uploaded by the user. So, in your settings define,

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

Then, inside your template append `/{{MEDIA_URL}}` in front of `{{item.photo}}`.

And in your urls.py file, to the urlpatterns append:

```
+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This ought to sort the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the *URL* of the photo correctly. In your template, replace the line

```
<img src = "{{item.photo}}", width = "150", height = "250">
```

with

```
<img src = "{{item.photo.url}}", width = "150", height = "250">
```

Comment: Oh... I see that Gocht suggests the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't specified a `media` folder. In your `settings.py` you need this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
```

And `photos/to_trade` should be inside this `media` folder. Also you need to use `{{item.photo.url}}` in your template instead of `{{item.photo}}`