# Display images on Django Template Site

Tags: python, django, image, static

I read a lot about including image files, but i still don't get it :(

my models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='poster/', blank=True)
```

my index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "{{movie.image_file}}" %}" />
```

The pictures are saved on harddisk /myapp/poster

Thanks for helping.

Got it!

```
<img src="
    {% if movie.image_file %}
        {{ movie.image_file.url }}
    {% else %}
        another-image.jpg
    {% endif %}"
/>
```

urls.py

```
+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
added MEDIA_URL
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an ImageField URL within a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850535/how-to-get-an-imagefield-url-within-a-template)

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30626791/3945375)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
<img src="{{ movie.image_file.url }}" />
```

User uploaded files go to your `MEDIA_ROOT` + the `upload_to` parameter in your model field, which is typically a different location that static files are served from when using the `{% static %}` template tag.

Since your field allows for `blank=True` you can use a conditional to show a different image, or no image at all: (spaces added to avoid wrapping)

```
<img src="
    {% if movie.image %}
        {{ movie.image_file.url }}
    {% else %}
        another-image.jpg
    {% endif %}"
/>
```

alternatively, you could add a model property that does the same thing, or you can just wrap the entire image tag in the if statement to hide it if the field is empty.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
The 'image_file' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Just using <img src="{{ movie.image_file }}" /> return blue boxes with question marks

Comment: I've updated the answer for you to show an alternative image if the field is empty.

Comment: I've tried, but still blue boxes. Also tried with movie.image_file.path

Comment: Have you verified that you have a value for the field? If so, what is the value when output to the Python repl?

Comment: The field is filled on the admin site und movie.image_file.path give me back the right path

Comment: What is your `MEDIA_ROOT`? Are you running with `DEBUG = True` locally? (staticfiles needs this)

Comment: Didn't set MEDIA_ROOT. DEBUG is True

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79973/discussion-between-brandon-and-bubbleboy).

Answer (score 1):

Set MEDIA_ROOT and add following lines at the end of your urls.py
`+static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='Index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In img src write `{{MODEL_NAME.FIELD_NAME.url}}`

This is only for development.
Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/